# Uport for private blockchain network

Tags: solidity, contract-development, uport, authentication

Can I use uport for authenticating users in a private blockchain network ? If yes, Are there any tutorials or implementations available for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

It's very much possible yes, take a look here: https://github.com/uport-project/specs/blob/develop/flows/privatechain.md